# Accessing Structure Members Problems

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am new to C++ classes and facing a simple problem but unfortunately didn't get the solution yet so that's why posting it here. I made a struct like this

```
struct mono_scan_temp
{
    double num_filters[1][1];
    double filter_data[1024][153][3];
    double shutter_speed[1][3];
    double resolution[1][153];
    double monochromator_gain[1][1];
    double zero[1][1];
    double saturation[1][1];
    double dark_noise[3][1024];
    double slit_size[1][1];
    double version[1][1];
};
```

This struct is in .h file then i instantiated it in the same header file like this

```
mono_scan_temp          scan_data_temp;
```

Now when i am trying to access its members from a main file it is giving this error.

> Error 43  error C2228: left of '.num_filters' must have
>   class/struct/union

The members of this struct will hold a data from .mat file like this

```
Mat_VarReadData(mat,field_num_filters,scan_data_temp.num_filters,start_num_filters,stride_num_filters,edge_num_filters);

for(i=0;i<field_num_filters->dims[0];i++)
for(j=0;j<field_num_filters->dims[1];j++)
printf("%f \n  ",scan_data_temp.num_filters[i][j]);
```

and also the header file is included in the main file.

I know it a simple problem but sorry in advance for my limited knowledge.

Looking forward for a favorable response.

Thanks

Comment: You aren't showing us the code that's actually generating the error, so it's impossible to help you.

Comment: all of the various `[1]`s make no sense.. unnecessary complexity

Comment: `double num_filters[1][1]` ? Um, that looks interesting.

Comment: You are probably not including the header file with this definition in your main cpp file

Comment: You may avoid the object declaration in the header. When you include this header in multiple source files, linker will complain about multiple symbols.

Comment: double num_filters[1][1]..they will hold the data from a .mat file given by matio library and matio only works for a matrix so for holding the data i have to make it like this...the data is only one double variable but its dimension is two as described by matio..so need to do this...

Comment: Karthik and WhozCraig...i edited the question..Please have a look at it. thanks

Comment: Chris Hayes...now does it make sense...if still not then let me know please...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have a subexpression `XXX.num_filters`, and `XXX` isn't an object of type `mono_scan_temp`.

Defining `zero` to be a two-dimensional array of bound 1 in each dimension, and a member of a `struct`, is what those in the industry sometimes call a "code smell."

---

This line does not go in the header file; it should go in the `.cpp` file. To declare a global object as part of an interface in the header, add `extern` before the declaration: `extern mono_scan_temp scan_data_temp;`. This is in addition to defining in the `.cpp` file.

And although the rest of your program appears to be in C, this line does require C++, so be sure you are using a C++ compiler and the file name ends in `.cpp` (if that's really what you want).

```
mono_scan_temp          scan_data_temp;
```

Comment: I edited the question..can you please have a look at it again...thanks